# Building a matrix function one element at a time

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix, function-construction

I would like to define a function which produces an $N\times N$ matrix where each element is a function of the input values ($N$ is a fixed constant). However, each element of the function needs to be computed from a predefined list of values.

In the specific example I am working on, I have a two lists, `A` and `B`: `A` contains the $(i,j)$ matrix indices and `B` contains vectors $\vec{v}$ corresponding to those matrix indeces (in the same order) For this example my vectors are three dimensional. However in the first list some indices are repeated more than once. Consider if I have some function $g(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{v})$, and I want to define a matrix $f_{ij}(\vec{r})$ such that each element is the sum of $g(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{v})$ for each $\vec{v}$ which corresponds to the index $(i,j)$.

I could make a matrix by simply defining an empty matrix of zeroes and looping over the list index,

```
f = ConstantArray[0, {N, N}]
For[i = 1, i <= Length[A], i++,
  f[[ A[[i, 1]], A[[i, 2]] ]] += g[B[[i]].{x,y,0}]
]`
```

But I can't do this if `f` is a function

```
f[x_,y_] := ConstantArray[0, {N, N}]
For[i = 1, i <= Length[A], i++,
  f[[ A[[i, 1]], A[[i, 2]] ]] += g[B[[i]].{x,y,0}]]
]`
```

I'm sure there's better ways but I just wanted to give a basic example of how I was thinking of approaching it. For now I built the matrix for the first way, printed it out in `MatrixForm`, copied and defined `f[x_,y_] =` and pasted the entire matrix. This is obviously not ideal, especially for larger matrices.

Comment: Please provide A and B lists. Also function definition is `f[x_] := ...` and not `f[x_] = ...`. When you define `f[x_,y_] := ...`, you do not need to use double brackets as `f[[ a1, a2 ]]` to use it. `f[[ a1, a2 ]]` means the a2th element of a1th row of the matrix f.

Comment: Hi sorry if my question was unclear, I fixed the `:=` and clarified the code slightly. In the first example `f` is just a matrix and I am referencing its elements. In the second example (which is pseudocode), `f` is a function which returns a matrix, and I want to apply the same logic: `f[[i,j]]` (pseudocode: the `{i,j}` element of the matrix returned by `f[x_,y_]`) is the sum of all `g[B[[n]].{x,y,0}]` such that `A[[n]] = {i,j}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m = 10;
n = 10;
A = RandomInteger[{1, m}, {n, 2}];
B = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
sparsematrix = SparseArray[A -> g /@ (B.{x, y, 0}), {m, m}];
matrix = Normal[sparsematrix]
```

And as function

```
f = r \[Function] SparseArray[A -> g /@ (B.r), {m, m}]
```

or

```
f = r \[Function] Normal[SparseArray[A -> g /@ (B.r), {m, m}]]
```

If indices in `A` have duplicates, you have to switch to *additive* matrix assembly wrapping `SparseArray` with some "decorations":

```
With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}],
  SparseArray[A -> g /@ (B.{x, y, 0}), {m, m}],
  SetSystemOptions[spopt]]
 ]
```

The wrapping with `` Internal`WithLocalSettings `` ensures that, afterwards, the value of `"TreatRepeatedEntries"` will be the same as before.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was not aware that `SpareArray` could be used in this way. I also haven't seen `\[Function]` used like this but it makes sense. However I still have the same problem that I started with which is that in the list `A` there are repeated indices, and I want to sum the corresponding `g[B.r]`.

Comment: Kai, even better: Typing in Mathematica, you can enter `\[Function]` by typing "esc" "f" "n" "esc".

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty neat, I have no experience using these sorts of system options, I don't have much experience beyond what is in the basic documentation!

Comment: how would I generalize this to make `f` a function of `x` and `y`, instead of the vector `r`?

Comment: Do you mean `f = {x,y} \[Function] SparseArray[A -> g /@ (B.{x,y,0}), {m, m}]`?

Comment: this would be equivalent to if I wrote `f[{x_,y_}]` correct? This works fine for what I'm doing, I was just curious if I could define it to be `f[x_,y_]`. Writing `f = x,y \[Function]` etc doesn't work.

Comment: @Kai Nope, `f = {x,y} \[Function] ...` is "equivalent" to `f[x_,y_] := ...`.